# Issue while trying to make a common method

Tags: c#

I am trying to refactor some code. So the code I am trying to refactor is this

```
var userApp = string.Join(",", items.Where(x => x.LicenseType == 1).Select(x => x.GroupName));

var groupApp = string.Join(",", items.Where(x => x.LicenseType == 2).Select(x => x.GroupName));

var totalUsedLicense = GetTotalFreeLicense(schoolCode, userApp, groupApp);

foreach (var item in totalUsedLicense)
{
    items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GroupName == item.GroupName).AvailableLicense = items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GroupName == item.GroupName).TotalLicense - item.Count;
}
```

Type of items can be `List<ApplicationListDto>` or `List<AdUserApplicationDto>` - they both inherit from `BaseApplicationDto`, 
where the common properties are.

Now I want to make a function where I can pass items as a parameter. How should I do this?

I am trying to get rid of the redundant code here

```
if (isList) 
{
    if (data.Count <= 0) return;

    List<AdUserApplicationDto> userApplicationDto = data;

    var items = userApplicationDto;

    var userApp = string.Join(",", items.Where(x => x.LicenseType == 1).Select(x => x.GroupName));
    var groupApp = string.Join(",", items.Where(x => x.LicenseType == 2).Select(x => x.GroupName));

    var totalUsedLicense = GetTotalFreeLicense(schoolCode, userApp, groupApp);

    foreach (var item in totalUsedLicense)
    {
        items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GroupName == item.GroupName).AvailableLicense = items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GroupName == item.GroupName).TotalLicense - item.Count;
    }
}
else
{
    Page<ApplicationListDto> userApplicationDto = data;

    if (userApplicationDto.TotalItems <= 0) return;

    var items = userApplicationDto.Items;



    var userApp = string.Join(",", items.Where(x => x.LicenseType == 1).Select(x => x.GroupName));
    var groupApp = string.Join(",", items.Where(x => x.LicenseType == 2).Select(x => x.GroupName));

    var totalUsedLicense = GetTotalFreeLicense(schoolCode, userApp, groupApp);

    foreach (var item in totalUsedLicense) {
        items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GroupName == item.GroupName).AvailableLicense = items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GroupName == item.GroupName).TotalLicense - item.Count;
    }

}
```

Comment: Write a function accepting a ref to IList<BaseApplicationDto> as a parameter.

Comment: @Max - they'd still need to use e.g. the LINQ `.Cast` operator on their list and create a new list if they did that. A `List<AdUserApplicationData>` is *not* an `IList<BaseApplicationDto>`, as you can find asked and answered *innumerable* times here on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a method to accept different types of list with a common base type, do this:

```
public void SomeAction<T>(List<T> list) where T : BaseApplicationDto
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You use the type of the base class as the type of the list..

```
public abstract class Common
{
    public string CommonString { get; set; }
}

public class B : Common
{

}


public class A : Common
{

}

public class ABConsumer
{
    public void DoSomething(List<Common> myList)
    {
        List<Common> EmptyStrings = myList.Where(x => x.CommonString == string.Empty).ToList();
    }
}
```

You can now access properties of the base class of both classes.

This is simple inheritance.

### Edit

It'll require a cast to from any given type: A or B to Common before it can be passed. If casting is an issue another good example using conditional generics can be used as shown in @ikkentims answer.

Comment: This requires casting the list to type `List<Common>`

Comment: Are you sure? Because I don't think it requires any further casting. I'd recommend running this and seeing the results first.

Comment: As commented on the question, parameter `List<Common>` does not accept `List<A>` or `List<B>` as a value, you'd have to build a new list using Linq's `.Cast<Common>().ToList`

Comment: True. I misunderstood your comment. It'll indeed require a cast. I've edited my answer a little :)